# Salzmann's topological loop example

Tags: abstract-algebra, quasigroups

I've been looking for loop examples and stumbled upon [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296794/examples-of-proper-loops-in-mathbbr) post.
The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2343222/1188507) describes a specific operation on $\mathbb{R} $, namely this:

$$x\ast t =
\begin{cases}
\ x+\frac{1}{2}t, &\text{ if }\  \frac{x}{t}\in (-\infty, -\frac{3}{2}]\cup [1,+\infty), \\\ \frac{1}{2}x+t, &\text{ if } \ \frac{x}{t}\in  [-\frac{2}{3}, 1], \\\ 2x+2t,&\text{ if }\ \frac{x}{t}\in  [-\frac{3}{2}, -\frac{2}{3}].
\end{cases}$$

My question is: do we implicitly define that $ x \ast 0 = x $? Division by zero is undefined and I would assume some kind of special case or at least a mentioning, especially because we are interested in a neutral element which is exactly $ 0 $.

So, is my suggestion right?